# VBScript Class Private array of classes constantly Empty after assignment

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, wsh, windows-scripting

I am having an issue where I have a class with a property that is an array. A Load method resizes the array to the number of entries in a file, creates a new Entry class for that file entry, and assigns it to a new element in the property array. However, when I try to use this array outside of my Load method, the array maintains the correct sizing, but all elements are "Empty". Below is basically what I am trying to do. I'm assuming this is a scoping issue with the assignment of the new Entry class, but I am not sure how to correct this being new to VBScript. Below is some quick code to give you an idea of what I'm trying.

```
Class Entry
    Public Name
End Class

Class Config
    Private theArray()

    Public Sub Load()
        ...
        Do While Not configFile.AtEndOfStream

        if(UBound(theArray) < theCount) Then
            ReDim Preserve theArray(theCount)
        End If

        Set theArray(theCount) = new Entry

        theArray(theCount).Name = "Bobby Joe Sue"
        Wscript.Echo theArray(theCount).Name & " is working"
    End Sub

    Public Function GetList()
        GetList = theArray
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, if I create an instance of the Config class, call the load method, assign a variable to the GetList result, I can loop through the array and it will be the correct size. HOWEVER, every entry in the array is Empty instead of an instance of the Entry class where I can access Entry.Name. Does anyone have any advice on what to do to fix this?

Comment: (1) remove the EVIL "On Error Resume Next" (2) Post the code fragment that uses .GetList() (3) swear that you increment theCount

Comment: On Error Resume Next and missing Option Explicit will get you in the end. mwhaaa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array initialization doesn't work. Change your `Class Config` like this:

```
Class Config
  Private theArray

  Private Sub class_initialize()
    theArray = Array()
  End Sub

  '...
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss something.

```
Set oConfig = New Config
oConfig.Load
aList = oConfig.List
Wscript.Echo "Type: " & TypeName(aList(0))
Wscript.Echo "Name: " & aList(0).Name

'> Bobby Joe Sue is working
'> Type: Entry
'> Name: Bobby Joe Sue

Class Entry
    Public Name
End Class

Class Config
    Private theArray()
    Private theCount

    Public Property Get List()
        List = theArray
    End Property

    Public Sub Load()
        theCount = theCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve theArray(theCount)
        Set theArray(theCount) = new Entry
        theArray(theCount).Name = "Bobby Joe Sue"
        Wscript.Echo theArray(theCount).Name & " is working"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        theCount = -1
    End Sub
End Class
```